# How to wget a file without getting the html instead?

Tags: wget

I'm trying to download a [file](https://huggingface.co/distilbert-base-uncased/blob/main/vocab.txt) using:

```
wget https://huggingface.co/distilbert-base-uncased/blob/main/vocab.txt
```

I'm expecting to get the .txt file, however, I get the page html instead.

I tried `wget --max-redirect=2 --trust-server-names <url>` based on the suggestions [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45959/wget-is-returning-an-html-page-instead-of-original-file) and `wget -m <url>` which downloads the entire website, and a few other variations that also don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wget https://huggingface.co/distilbert-base-uncased/blob/main/vocab.txt
```

This point wget to HTML page even though it has .txt suffix. After visting it I found there is link to text file itself under raw, which you should be able to use with wget following way

```
wget https://huggingface.co/distilbert-base-uncased/raw/main/vocab.txt
```

If you need to reveal true type of file without downloading it you might use `--spider` option, in this case

```
wget --spider https://huggingface.co/distilbert-base-uncased/blob/main/vocab.txt
```

gives output containing

```
Length: 7889527 (7,5M) [text/html]
```

and

```
wget --spider https://huggingface.co/distilbert-base-uncased/raw/main/vocab.txt
```

gives output containing

```
Length: 231508 (226K) [text/plain]
```

Answer (score 1):

How come no-one is mentioning the .netrc file? If the web site requires a login, there must be a .netrc file that folds credential information. That is what tripped me up when I had a similar problem.